# Sharing Rule - Roles and Internal Subordinates

Tags: community, permissions, sharing-rule

On Lead object:

I would like to understand how Sharing rule works in my case.  The following is my role hierarchy World Wide Sales -> Inside Sales WW -> BDR.  If I create a sharing rule owner in Role, Roles and Internal Subordinates World Wide Sales share with role Inside Sales WW Lead Read/Write. My question is, will users with role BDR able to edit leads own by World Wide Sales?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the way you've shown it, `World Wide Sales` is at the top of a role hierarchy just above `Inside Sales WW` with `BDR` at the bottom of the hierarchy as below.

```
World Wide Sales
     |
     v
Inside Sales WW
     |
     v
    BDR
```

From [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_data_set_categories.htm&language=en_US), Roles and Internal Subordinates means the following:

> All roles defined for your organization. This includes all of the users in the specified role plus all of the users in roles below that role, excluding partner portal and Customer Portal roles.

So the answer would be "yes", users with the Role BDR would potentially be able to edit records shared with users in the World Wide Sales Role. The appropriate way to handle this is to only add the specific roles or profiles to a sharing group that you want to extend the permissions on an object. Groups can be added to form larger groups to make it easier to extend permissions for an object.

Answer (score 0):

I've read this differently. It appears that the BDR Role would not be able to edit records owned by the World Wide Sales Role by default or with your sharing rule. This assumes the Org Wide default is Private.

Answer (score 0):

From Salesforce: TLDR is yes this includes the BDR Role

All roles defined for your organization. This includes all of the users in the specified role plus all of the users in roles below that role. This is only available when no Salesforce Experience sites or portals are enabled for your organization.